# How can I suspend/resume a running program from command line in Windows?

Tags: windows, operating-system, mingw, process

I am trying to pause a running program using an OS command script in Windows 7.

After searching StackOverflow/Search-Engines, it seems most suggestions involve the use of sysinternals process explorer in which programs can easily be suspended and resumed using the mouse. However, I would like to use the command line to do the same and cannot figure out how.

Can anyone tell me how to pause/resume programs from the command line?

Note. I am using Windows 7 and MinGW.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out SysInternals PsSuspend:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend

To suspend, use this.

```
PsSuspend ProcessImageName.exe
```

To resume the process, use this command.

```
PsSuspend -r ProcessImageName.exe
```